# part of proof about stochastic processess

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I need help proving a part of a proof. The exercise in the book( *Exercise 3.14 in Bernt Øksendal*: *Stochastic Differential equations)* is given as to prove something, but I will only talk about the first part of the proof in this post:

The proof I am talking about:

> Assume that you have a stocastic process $B_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given
> on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}$, P). The filtration
> $\mathcal{F}_t$ is defined as the sigma algebra generated by the sets
> $\{B_s^{-1}{(A}): A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n), s \le t\}$.(This is
> supposed to be the natural filtration, or the filtration generated by
> the process.
>
> Then:
>
> $h$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ -measurable iff it can be written as the
> pointwise limit, of sums off functions of the form
> $g_1(B_{t_1})g_2(B_{t_2})\cdots g_k(B_{t_k})$, where each g is
> continous and all the $t_j\le t$.

**Now the first part of the proof, which I am stuck on, is to explain why it is enough for h to be bounded?**

Here is what I tried:

My first attempt is to assume that h is not bounded, and assume that the theorem holds for bounded functions and then try to approximate.

I tried to divide the range in partitions according to the absolute value of h. For instance $h_1=h\mathcal{X}_{(\{\omega: |h(\omega)|<1\}} $, $h_2=h\mathcal{X}_{(\{\omega: |h(\omega)|<2\}} $. These functions converges pointwise to h, and I can use the theorem to get a sequence of the form I like on each of them. The only way to continue here is with some sort of sequence to works for all the functions, but the problem with using a classical diagonal argument is that I can not choose one sequence to be a subsequence of the earlier ones. So it doesn't really work.

My last idea was to work with $h_1=h\mathcal{X}_{(\{\omega: |h(\omega)|<1\}} $, $h_2=h\mathcal{X}_{(\{\omega: 1\le|h(\omega)|<2\}} $ etc. Now the $h_n$ won't converge but the sums of $h_n$ will converge to $h$. If I use the theorem separately on each of the $h_n$, I am close to having my result, but the problem is this: If for instance $f^1_k\rightarrow h_1, f^2_k\rightarrow h_2$ etc., where $f_k=f_{k-1}+\prod_{i=1}^k g_i$, where the g's are given by the theorem. Then it is difficult showing that for instance we can pick up a function that converges and have our properties, because we only have that they converge pointwise to $0$ where they are cut off, and when I introduce more terms, I don't see how to get the convergence correct. Also if I introduce $\mathcal{X}_{\{\omega|j-1\le|h(\omega)|<j\}}$ to the sequence $f_k^j$ then I lose the continuity part.

Any tips or hints here?

Comment: The [filters] tag is not about filtrations.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I  apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it does not seem to be true (in general) that, rephrasing it, if $h_{n}^j\to h_n$ a.e. (or pointwise) as $j\to \infty$ and $h_n\to h$ a.e. (or pointwise) as $n\to \infty$, then there is a subsequence that $h_{n_k}^{j_k}\to h$ a.e. (or pointwise) as $k\to \infty$. The problem is that the subsequence can vary for each point.

Nevertheless I would say that Exercise 3.14 can be solved using $L^1$ convergence (and then taking an almost everywhere convergent subsequence). In particular, taking $h_n^\pm:=\max\{h^\pm,n\}$, $h_n=h_n^+-h_n^-$ are bounded and converge in $L^1$ to $h$ by the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Then, if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $g=g_{n,\varepsilon}$ (as described in the exercise) such that $\|h_n-g\|_{L^1(P)}<\varepsilon/2$, then
$$
\|h-g\|_{L^1(P)}<\varepsilon
$$
if $n$ is large enough. Thus, it is enough to find that $g$ for bounded Borel functions.